# Can application access permanent, local storage in debug build?

Tags: android

I'm building an app, which saves files in local storage. When I test the app, everything works fine, but when I start the app a second time in Android Studio, it does not load the content, it should have saved in the last session. My answer is: Does an application use local storage when tested in debug mode? Or is my code just buggy?

Comment: maybe tell us about your code, so we know which kind of method you use to access the storage?

Comment: What is the error? There should not be an issue in debug build!

Comment: check your logcat, maybe you have some errors there
for now I can say only that it's pretty sure that your code is buggy :)

Answer (score 0):

> Does an application use local storage when tested in debug mode?

Yes.

> is my code just buggy?

Possibly. That could be in the session-saving logic, in the loading logic, or possibly elsewhere.